# Why are modal verbs never used with "has" even when the subject is singular?

Tags: modal-verbs, conjugation

Why is it that modal verbs are always used with "have," regardless of whether the subject is singular or plural? For example, you would say "She *has* been here" and "They *have* been here," but you would say "She would *have* been here" and "They would *have* been here." Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule I learnt (I'm Portuguese, by the way) states that after modal verbs the main verb is used in the infinitive, so the form of the verb 'to have' is determined by before it there being a modal verb and not the 3rd person singular 'she'. I think.

Comment: That sounds right. After all, we say "He/She/They would _be_," rather than either _is_ or _are._ It must be because we use the infinitive, then.